# Webforms application .NET 4 in Visual 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

I have a quick question concerning creating an web forms application with visual 2013 express. I'm working on older servers (Windows 2003) which cannot handle anything greater than .NET 4.

When I go to create my application with visual studio 2013 I go to the Visual Studio 2012 tab, where MVC 4 is listed and choose the web forms application there. What I've learned though, is that it automatically sets the framework to 4.5 still, so I have to change it to 4. In doing so, the NuGet packages get messed up and I have to reinstall them all. I discovered after reinstalling them all it's still messed up and I'm getting build errors. I assumed because I choose to use an older version of webforms, it would automatically set my framework up for me as well. Doing a little troubleshooting I discovered that even when you choose to create a MVC 4 application it still sets the framework to 4.5 and messes everything up when you try to change it.

I'm thinking about just downloading an older version of visual but I don't have admin rights to my computer and that is a pain. Any insight?

I'm painfully new to this material, so everything in layman's terms is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you select MVC 4 Web Application, or any of the other templates, there is a drop down at the top that allows you to select which Framework you would like to use.  I'm using professional, it may be different in express.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Yay, I'm just a ditz. Appreciate it!